# htpasswd.users in nagios apache linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, nagios

I am installing NAGIOS, I came to know that I need to generate a file htpasswd.users related to apche.
How can I generate this, any scripts for that??

Comment: Have you looked at the apache documentation at http://httpd.apache.org?

Comment: Also worth noting: Nagios can use any auth mechanism that httpd can use; there are literally dozens of them. htpasswd is probably not the best option.

Answer (score 1):

The apache package already provides a program called `htpasswd` that does this for you.

However, you will still have to adjust your apache configuration to enable the authentication to take place.  Just having a generated password file will not cause apache to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`htpasswd` binary, included with Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htpasswd.html), is what you should use to manage an `htpasswd` file.